# Docker image run error on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, ghost-blog

I'm trying to install ghost, a open-source blogging platform on Google Cloud Platform using docker.
I'm following this tutorial, [Link](https://medium.com/@stevenc81/self-hosted-ghost-blog-on-gcp-free-tier-d91cd38b3bc4)

I successfully installed docker, and I'm trying to install and run the ghost container image by following the tutorial in the link.

```
$ sudo docker run -d -p 80:2368 --name ghost -e url="https://<your blog domanin>" -v ~/ghost:/var /lib/ghost/content ghost
```

However, these are my results,

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any suggestions?

For any help, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a f1-micro instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete whitespace.

`~/ghost:/var /lib/ghost/content`
-> `~/ghost:/var/lib/ghost/content`